# How to hide inner points in Excel 365 boxplots using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, office365, hide, boxplot

I have a macro that creates multiple boxplots on one chart using

```
Set MyBoxPlots = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(406, xlBoxwhisker)
```

but each boxplot always shows 'inner points' as soon I add a series

```
.SeriesCollection(SeriesNumber).Values = SelectedXRange
```

I can manually uncheck this option for each boxplot, but I have many dozens of them.  The link shows an example where I have manually adjusted the middle plots: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KXS3TtCUA4QXWNjtKYbTLGdPm3sn7HYr

What VBA code provides switching inner points on and off?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can manually uncheck them, why don't you do it and record a macro to see the code, produced by the manul task? Then it would be easy to adjust it.

Comment: Yes, I tried macro recording but creating a boxplot produces almost no code in the macro! (And thanks for formatting my code lines properly.)

Comment: Well, you may consider adding the macro-recorded code to the question. I cannot replicate, I do not have office365.

Comment: As I said, the macro is of no use:    Sub Macro1() ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
  End Sub     (Sorry I don't know how to format yet.)

Comment: I have the same issue. The VBA macro only captured the this: ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select, which I believe is my action to double click the series...